# I have two sets of code which both function similarly. Which of them is more practical?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project using C# that requires two forms; one to be filled out, the other to be display what was filled out. Problem is, I'm unsure which of the two sets of code is more efficient for the compiler and will take up less RAM as they both are quite different in execution.

Here is an example of the first one:
Method1:
Form 1

```
Form1 frm1;
Form2 frm2;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Currently, I have instantiated an object of the current form.
        frm1 = this;
    }

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //From there, I pass it into the second form.
        frm2 = new Form2(frm1);
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form 2

```
From1 frm1;

public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.frm1 = frm1;
    }

//From here, I would make the change to the first form. For example:

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.listbox.Items.Add("string");
    }
```

Here is an example of the second set:
Form 1:

```
Form2 frm2;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here, I pass in an existing listbox to the next form.
        frm2 = new Form2(listbox);
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form 2

```
ListBox listbox;

public Form2(ListBox listbox)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listbox = listbox;
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I make the change here.
        listbox.Items.Add("string");
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you are asking is it better to send to form2 a reference to form1, or just to a specific control? Performane wise there should be no difference.
I would go with the first option, since it's more maintainable. - Suppose you will want to change another control's properties from form2 later on? With the first option you already have the reference, with the second option you will have to also change the constructor, the private members, and the instantiation of form2 in form1.

Comment: Is that so? I originally believed that it would be better practice to pass in only the things I needed to access rather than the entire form (That's what I'm taught, at least). I can see how this makes sense, though; as you said-- anything that may need to be changed on the first form from the second one can be done without having to alter other aspects such as the constructor. Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Actually, this brings about another problem (unless I'm misinformed, or doing this wrong): when I'm using the first option, I must make anything I wish to make a change to public. I've been taught that having too many things public and/or static would cause problems when a project becomes larger. Whereas this would not be the case if I pass in specific controls. Perhaps both ways would be used depending on the situation?

Comment: You don't need to make them public, they are internal by default, and that means the cam be accessed from anywhere in the assembly.

Comment: OK, I see. My computer defaults them to protected. I'll try experimenting with it more from here. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I might have made mistake - I've tested now and seems like in my visual studio (2013) the default modifier of new controls dropped on the form is actually `private`...